# Cómo puedo hacer un programa que entregue la parte decimal de un numero real ingresado en bash?

Tags: git-bash

Me entregan un número, cualquiera que lleve decimal (ejemplo 4.5) y debe aparecer SOLO la parte decimal (en este caso la parte decimal de 4.5 es 0.5) y eso es lo que debería aparecer solo el 0.5
Cómo puedo hacerlo con una variable?, o sea que la persona ingrese cualquier número decimal y le entregue solo esa parte

Comment: Agradecería mucho su ayuda, la verdad que me cuesta mucho bash y enserio agradezco si me ayudan :D

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Answer (score 0):

Quizá esto te ayude:

```
echo Número? 
read n
echo $n | awk -F. '{print 0"."$2}'
```

Explicacion:

El echo y read supongo que ya lo sabes así que pasaré al awk. El parámetro-F. Le indica que el separador es un "." por lo tanto a cualquier número decimal lo separará en dos, siendo $1 la parte entera y $2 la parte decimal, por lo tanto solo queda imprimirlo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, sin embargo, recuerda que las preguntas que carecen de un intento claro o que no aporten un mínimo de código que muestre que el OP lo ha intentado de alguna manera, terminan cerradas, lo cual hace que tu aporte se pierda. Saludos